# Scrolling glitch with Bootstrap's top .navbar on iPhone 5 Safari, hovers menu items randomly

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, mobile-safari

I've run into a problem with Bootstrap's .top-nav only on Safari for iPhone. When scrolling through a .dropdown-menu, after releasing my finger from the phone, it seems to "keep" or "catch" the location my finger was and hover over that list-item, keeping the CSS style for that element's :hover. It doesn't attempt to direct the url anywhere, but it can be a little confusing to the end-user.

This does not happen on my Android phone or in the desktop browser at extra small width (no-touch).

I understand this could be a difficult question to answer, but I'm hoping somebody else has run into this problem on their own and knows the root cause / a fix.

Bootstrap 3, latest version of Safari for iPhone 5. Thank you!

edit: oh, also, this is Bootstrap integrated into Adobe Business Catalyst. I don't think that should make a difference, but it might be worth saying.

Comment: `top-nav` is not part of Bootstrap

Comment: Right -- .navbar instead. My bad :)